# read txt, count each alphabet using linked list

Tags: c

```
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_OF_ALPHABET 26
#define MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100


typedef struct _CharFrequency
{
    char character;
    int frequency;
    struct _CharFrequency * next;
}CharFrequency;

typedef CharFrequency* pCharFrequency;

pCharFrequency pHead = NULL;

void initList();
void addNode(char ch);
void printAllNode(pCharFrequency pHead);

int main()
{
    int i = 0, cnt = 0;
    FILE *pFile;
    char readLine[1024], *ptr;
    char *token = " \t\n.";

    pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\dataset.txt", "r");
    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File open failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fgets(readLine, 1024, pFile) != NULL)
    {
        ptr = strtok(readLine, token);
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++)
            {
                addNode(ptr[i]);
            }

            ptr = strtok(NULL, token);
        }
    }
    printAllNode(pHead);


    return 0;
}

void initList()
{

    pHead = (CharFrequency*)malloc(sizeof(CharFrequency));

    if (!pHead)
    {
        printf("Fault\n");
        return;
    }

    pHead->character = '\0';
    pHead->frequency = 0;
    pHead->next = NULL;
}

void addNode(char ch)
{
    int i = 0;
    pCharFrequency pNode = NULL;
    pCharFrequency pCurrent= NULL;

    if (isalpha(ch) == 0)
        return;

    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        ch = ch + 32;

    printf("%c ", ch);

    for (pCurrent = pHead; pCurrent != NULL ; pCurrent = pCurrent->next)
    {
        if (pCurrent->character == ch)
        {
            pCurrent->frequency++;
        }
        else
        {
            pNode = (CharFrequency*)malloc(sizeof(CharFrequency));
    pNode->frequency = 0;
    pNode->next = NULL;

    pNode->character = ch;
    pNode->frequency++;

    pCurrent->next = pNode;
        }
    }

    pNode = (CharFrequency*)malloc(sizeof(CharFrequency));
    pNode->frequency = 0;
    pNode->next = NULL;

    pNode->character = ch;
    pNode->frequency++;

    pCurrent->next = pNode;

}

void printAllNode(pCharFrequency pHead)
{
    pCharFrequency pCurrent;
    pCurrent = pHead;

    pCurrent = pHead;

    while (pCurrent->next != NULL) {
        printf("%c %d", pCurrent->character, pCurrent->frequency);
        pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
    }

}
```

I want to build a program that reads txt file, count only alphabet, and count them using linked list. I make struct called CharFrequency to count alphabet.
addNode function gets the character, checks if it's in the list or not, and count them.
It makes error when doing for() in the addNode function.

Comment: Any error in particular?  Syntax?  Segfault?  Nasal demons?

Comment: 'pNode->frequency = 0;' pNode dereferenced with no guarantee of initialization.

Comment: What did you fid out when you stepped through this code with your debugger?

Comment: (0x008C527E, Huffman Coding.exe): 0xC0000005: 0x00000008
kind of this error
i think it's access violation

Comment: Debugger....................

Comment: Your `addNode` logic is completely wrong. It adds a new node as soon as there is any character that doesn't match. Instead it should search the while list and only add a new node at the end of that search if the character was not found in the list already.

Comment: Linked lists can be hard to understand when you first start using them. You have to meticulously walk through the code. So debuggers help a lot. Start by deleting the else from your for loop in an effort to keep things as simple as possible. Set a flag when you increment the frequency and have the for stop looping if the flag is true. After the for loop only add the node to your list if the flag is false. Your new node becomes the head. Watch out for things that are NULL (like the head).

Comment: Well, I don't know why people try to define their own Lists, When List is avaible STL with so optimization options available

Comment: @Halo_HeroOfReach There is no STL in C.

Comment: Well, He can write this code in a c++ compiler for example Microsoft Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink about the logic inside your `addNode` method. It is adding a new node every time a character is not found in the list, and even if a match is found,the loop will continue until the last node adding a new node every time.

You could do something like this to get you started and experiment on it to make it more efficient.

```
pCharFrequency pNode = NULL;
pCharFrequency pCurrent= NULL;
pCharFrequency pTail= NULL;//this will keep track of the last node in the list 
                          //so that we use it to insert a new node
....//your other code

pCurrent = pHead;//start from the head
while (pCurrent!=NULL) 
{
    if (pCurrent->character == ch)
    {
        pCurrent->frequency++;
        return;//if a match was found, count and return
    }

    if(pCurrent->next == NULL)
        pTail=pCurrent;//save the pointer to the last node in the list if we reach to it

    pCurrent=pCurrent->next;//get the next node
}

//if we reach here, then we need to create a new node
pNode = (CharFrequency*)malloc(sizeof(CharFrequency));

if(pNode==NULL)
{ 
    //show error message
    return;
}
pNode->frequency = 1;
pNode->next = NULL;
pNode->character = ch;

if(pHead==NULL)
   pHead=pNode;//for the very first node,we just assign to head
else
  pTail->next = pNode;//otherwise set the last node's next to the node we just created
```